# Angular 2 Deployment Issue

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have deployed my angular 2 Cli project in Amazon Ec2. 
But I can't able run this. How can i run this project. When i am giving ng-serve command it builds and its displayed http://localhost:4200. How can i set default port and how can i run.

In local i have did **ng-serve** then i run it in my browser like **"localhost:4200"** it works. But in production, i don't know how to run.

Please give any solution.

Comment: `ng build --prod`, then copy the result to your server?   https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build

Comment: Actually i have tried like ng build --prod, but its bundling my files to dist/ directory but can't able to run in my browser and its not showing any sever  results like server name to navigate. Help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-serve` runs a local node server, you should never use that node server in production. it's a development server only.

run `ng build --prod` copy the generated bundles and files from /dist into your production environment. In file system that is the directory that your server is serving.

for AWS instructions for static website take a look at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/swh/website-hosting-intro.html

Comment: Actually i have tried like ng build --prod, but its bundling my files to dist/ directory but can't able to run in my browser and its not showing any sever  results like server name to navigate. Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: @vijayakumar I' not following.. serving a static site should be straight forward, this is not an angular cli issue.. angular cli generates the static artifacts in `dist` as I explained in my answer, you'll need to follow the steps for AWS static site to serve your app from AWS.